# word2vec gensim update learning rate

Tags: python, machine-learning, word2vec, gensim

I trained a w2v model on a big corpus, and I want to update it with a smaller one with new sentences (and new words).

In the first big training, I took the default parameters for alpha (0.025 with lin. decay  to 0.0001)
Now, I want to use `model.train` to update it. But from the doc I don't understand which (initial and final) learning rate will be used during this update of training.

From one side, if you also use 0.025 with lin. decay until 0.0001, it will be too strong for already existing words which appeared a lot in the first big corpus and that will be heavily changed, but from the other side for new words (added with model.build_vocab(sentences, update = True)) a low learning rate of 0.0001 is too small.

So my questions are :

1. What is the default behaviour of `model.train` in the API on new sentences regarding the learning rate?
2. How I should choose the learning rate in order to take into account this issue of old/new words ?
3. [aside question] Why when I use 2 times model.train on the same sentences, the second time, it doesn't update the vectors ?

Answer (score 1):

While you *can* keep training a `Word2Vec` model with newer examples, unless the *old* examples are also re-presented in an interleaved fashion, those new examples may not make the model any better – no matter how well you adjust the `alpha`.

That's because while training on the new examples, the model is only being nudged to get better at predicting their words, in those new contexts. If there are words missing from the new texts, their word-vectors remain unadjusted as the rest of the model drifts. Even to the extent the same words repeat, their new contexts will presumably be different in some important ways – or else why keep training with new data? – which incrementally dilutes or obsoletes all influence of the older training.

There's even a word for the tendency (but far from certainty) of neural-networks to worsen when presented new data: [catastrophic forgetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_interference).

So, the most supportable policy is to re-train with all relevant data mixed-together, to be sure it all has equal influence. If you're improvising some other shortcuts, you're in experimental territory, and there's little reliable documentation or published work that can make strong suggestions about the relative balance of learning-rates/epoch-counts/etc. Any possible answers would also depend very heavily on the relative sizes of the corpuses and vocabularies both at first, and then on any subsequent updates, and also on how important your specific project are factors like vector-stability-over-time, or relative-quality-of-different-vectors. So there'd be no one answer – just what tends to work in your particular setup.

(There's an experimental feature in `gensim` `Word2Vec` – some internal model properties that end `_lockf`. That stands for 'lock-factor'. They match 1-for-1 with the word-vectors, and for any slot where this lock-factor is set to 0.0, the word-vector ignores training updates. In this way, you can essentially 'freeze' some words – such as those you're confident won't be improved by more training – while letting others still update. This *might* help with drift/forgetting issues with updates, but issues of relative quality and correct `alpha`/`epochs` are still murky, requiring project-by-project experimentation.)

Specifically with regard to your numbered questions:

(1) Each call to `train()` will do the specified `epochs` number of passes over the data, and smoothly manage the learning-rate from the model's configured starting `alpha` to `min_alpha` (unless you override those with extra parameters to `train()`.

(2) As above, there's no established rule-of-thumb because the issue is complicated, incremental training in this style isn't guaranteed to help, and even where it might help it'd depend highly on non-generalizable project specifics.

(3) If a second call to `train()` causes no changes to vectors, there may be something wrong with your corpus-iterator. Enable logging to at least the INFO level and make sure `train()` is taking the time, and showing the incremental progress, that indicates real model updates are happening.

Comment: how do I know that a word trained well and won't be improved by more training and so that I can freeze the specific word.

Comment: The best measures of word-vector quality will be project-specific. How were you planning to evaluate whether word-vectors were doing a good job on your problem? Do you have a robust, repeatable way to score word-vectors as being better or worse on some representative set of actions? Once you do, you can make good judgements about whether changes you're making to the word-vector training are improvements or not. But if you can't already score alternate sets of word-vectors as being better or worse, then incremental re-training is premature.

Comment: no I don't have any way to score word-vectors.  Just wondering can we say that the more frequent word in the vocabulary list, they trained well than the less frequent words?

Comment: In general, word-vectors for words with many varied examples will be "better", in relation to each other, for most purposes, than word-vectors for rare words. So you'd always like more realistic examples of a rare word's usages (not just repetitions of the same few nonvaried uses). But this observation can't really help you know whether one set of parameters is better than another, or a batch of incremental training is helping, overall, with respect to words less-represented in the batch. To make that decision requires holistic evaluation of the whole set of word-vectors vis-a-vis each other.